# Plotting a shape once when price is above the Kumo Cloud

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api, trend

*Trying to plot an arrow up shape once whenever price is above the cloud. This plotted shape shouldn't be repeated until we have another price above cloud event.*

**Code so far:**

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='My Ichimoku Cloud', shorttitle='Ichimoku', overlay=true)
conversionPeriods = input.int(9, minval=1, title='Conversion Line Periods')
basePeriods = input.int(26, minval=1, title='Base Line Periods')
laggingSpan2Periods = input.int(52, minval=1, title='Lagging Span 2 Periods')
displacement = input.int(26, minval=1, title='Displacement')

donchian(len) =>
    math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))

conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)
leadLine1 = math.avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)
plot(conversionLine, color=color.new(#00e5ff, 0), title='Conversion Line')
plot(baseLine, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), title='Base Line')
plot(close, offset=-displacement + 1, color=color.new(#459915, 0), title='Lagging Span', display=display.none)
p1 = plot(leadLine1, offset=displacement - 1, color=color.new(color.green, 0), title='Lead 1', display=display.none)
p2 = plot(leadLine2, offset=displacement - 1, color=color.new(color.red, 0), title='Lead 2', display=display.none)
fill(p1, p2, color=leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? color.new(color.green, 90) : color.new(color.red, 90))

topOfCloudLine = float(na)
priceAboveCloud = bool(na)
if leadLine1 > leadLine2
    topOfCloudLine := leadLine1
else
    if leadLine1 < leadLine2
        topOfCloudLine := leadLine2

if close > topOfCloudLine
    priceAboveCloud := true

plotshape(priceAboveCloud, style=shape.arrowup, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), size=size.tiny, offset = displacement + 1)
```

**Current Output:** [image]

Comment: the tricky part is the displacement logic..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `ta.crossover()` and `ta.crossunder()` functions. Those will return `true` only once there is a cross. So you can do something like this:

```
price_crossed_top = ta.crossover(close, topOfCloudLine)
```

And then use `price_crossed_top` as a condition to draw your shape.

Comment: I changed the line of code to topOfCloudLine[displacement] and it works perfectly!